# python pandas beginner: multi-dimensional data-analysis workflow (groupby+agg+plot)

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm new into pandas and try to learn how to process my multi-dimensional data.

### My data

Let's assume, my data is a big CSV of the columns ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']. This data describes some simulation results, where ['A', 'B', ..., 'F'] are simulation parameters and 'G' is one of the ouputs (only existing output in this example!).

**EDIT / UPDATE:**
As *Boud* suggested in the comments, let's generate some data which is compatible to mine:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np

npData = np.zeros(5000, dtype=[('A','i4'),('B','f4'),('C','i4'), ('D', 'i4'), ('E', 'f4'), ('F', 'i4'), ('G', 'f4')])

A = [0,1,2,3,6] # param A: int
B = [1000.0, 10.000] # param B: float
C = [100,150,200,250,300] # param C: int
D = [10,15,20,25,30] # param D: int
E = [0.1, 0.3] # param E: float
F = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] # param F = random-seed = int -> 10 runs per scenario

# some beta-distribution parameters for randomizing the results in column "G"
aDistParams = [ (6,1),
                (5,2),
                (4,3),
                (3,4),
                (2,5),
                (1,6),
                (1,7) ]

counter = 0
for i in itertools.product(A,B,C,D,E,F):
    npData[counter]['A'] = i[0]
    npData[counter]['B'] = i[1]
    npData[counter]['C'] = i[2]
    npData[counter]['D'] = i[3]
    npData[counter]['E'] = i[4]
    npData[counter]['F'] = i[5]

    np.random.seed = i[5]
    npData[counter]['G'] = np.random.beta(a=aDistParams[i[0]][0], b=aDistParams[i[0]][1])
    counter += 1

data = pd.DataFrame(npData)
data = data.reindex(np.random.permutation(data.index)) # shuffle rows because my original data doesn't give any guarantees
```

Because the parameters ['A', 'B', ..., 'F'] are generated as a cartesian-product (meaning: nested for-loops; a priori), i want to use groupby for obtaining each possible 'simulation scenario' before analysing the output.

The parameter 'F' describe multiple runs for each scenario (each scenario defined by 'A', 'B', ..., 'E' ; let's assume, that 'F' is the random-seed), so my code becomes:

```
grouped = data.groupby(['A','B','C','D','E'])
# -> every group defines one simulation scenario

grouped_agg = grouped.agg(({'G' : np.mean}))
# -> the mean of the simulation output in 'G' over 'F' is calculated for each group/scenario
```

### What do i want to do now?

- **I**: display all the (unique) values of each scenario-parameter within these groups -> grouped_agg gives me an iterable of tuples, where for example all the entries at each position 0 give me all the values for 'A' (so with a few lines of python i would get my unique values, but maybe there is a function for that)

  - **Update: my approach**
  - `list(set(grouped_agg.index.get_level_values('A')))` (when interested in 'A'; using set for obtaining unique values; probably not the stuff you want to do, if you need high performance)
  - => `[0, 1, 2, 3, 6]`
- **II**: generate some plots (of lower dimension) -> i need to make some variables constant and filter/select my data before plotting (therefore step I needed) =>

  - 'B' const
  - 'C', const
  - 'E' const
  - 'D' = x-axis
  - 'G' = y-axis / output from my aggregation
  - 'A' = one more dimension = multiple colors within 2d-plot -> one G/y-axis for each value of 'A'

  **How would i generate a plot like that?**

  I think, that reshaping my data is the key step and pandas plotting capabilities will handle it then. Maybe achieving a shape, where there are 5 columns (one for each value of parameter A) and the corresponding G-values for each index-selection + param-A-selection is enough, but i wasn't able to achieve that form yet.

Thanks for your input!

(i'm using pandas 0.12 within enthought canopy)

Sascha

Comment: Try to add data samples in your post

Comment: Occasionally I work with multi-dimensional data and thought Pandas would be a nice tool for post-processing, though I've never used it. Now, after struggling quite a lot I must say I didn't achieve the streamlined work flow I was expecting. Especially taking arbitrary slices from the data proved difficult, which is probably inherent to the 2D nature of `DataFrame`. Perhaps you're better off just storing your data in a numpy array..

Comment: Until my first steps with pandas, i processed my data without any specialized libraries and used stuff like "groupby" (itertools) and all that numpy/scipy functions. My hope was, that pandas allows me to do the same processing in a much cleaner way (less but more elegant/concise code) and keeping everything modular so that i would save "development-time" in the future. While there are a lot of blog-posts showing some potential of pandas, i still have problems with my application, despite the fact that is isn't that complex. I'm glad (in some way) to hear , that others have had problems too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I: If I understand your example and desired output, I don't see why grouping is necessary.

```
data.A.unique()
```

II: Updated....

I will implement the example you sketch above. Assume that we have averaged 'G' over the random seed ('F') like so:

```
data = data.groupby(['A','B','C','D','E']).agg(({'G' : np.mean})).reset_index()
```

Start by selecting the rows where B, C, and E have some constant values that you specify.

```
df1 = data[(data['B'] == const1) & (data['C'] == const2) & (data['E'] == const3)]
```

Now we want to plot 'G' as a function of 'D', with a different color for every value of 'A'.

```
df1.set_index('D').groupby('A')['G'].plot(legend=True)
```

I tested the above on some dummy data, and it works as you describe. The range of 'G' corresponding to each 'A' are plotting in the distinct color on the same axes.

III: I don't know how to answer that broad question.

IV: No, I don't think that's an issue for you here.

I suggest playing with simpler, small data sets and getting more familiar with pandas.

Comment: I: Thanks for mentioning the unique() function.
II: I'm processing multi-dimensional data: G = f(A,B,C,D,E,F). I use groupby to identify my cartesian-product-like scenarios (scenario = params 'A':'E' set/constant), then using aggregate to calculate the mean within this scenario (param 'F' is still a degree of freedom). Each relevant plot will choose one of these dimensions as x-Axis (e.g. 'D'), and 1:n dimensions embedded within the y-Axis (e.g. 'A' -> 5 colors) where 'G' are the values. But because G = f(A,B,C,D,E,F), all the other "open" variables have to be selected / made constant first!

Comment: Gotcha. Updated above.

Comment: Thank you Dan! It seems that i'm now able to do what i wanted to do and the code looks nice too (regarding readability and shortness).
One more tiny request: variable 'F' is a random-seed for a simulation-run within each scenario. Therefore i'm grouping (all the scenarios) and aggregating 'G' first (2nd code-block in question). Using your code-snippet on "grouped_agg.reset_index()" will produce my desired plot. Could you include this step in your answer please? (feel free to do it your way; i needed reset_index() to convert my indices to columns, so that i can use your snippet without changes)